# ng-submit & ng-click not working in iOS Ionic App, fires multiple times

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm creating a Cordova Ionic App for Android & iOS. I have created a registration form. When i click on "Register" button, the alert which I have written in function is coming but the same alert is coming again when I click anywhere on screen, means the alert is coming twice.

The same thing is working fine on Browser & Android.

i referred below link but it was not helpful:

[Ng-submit and ng-click fires many times i ionic iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105239/ng-submit-and-ng-click-fires-many-times-i-ionic-iphone-app)

Below is my code :

**HTML:**

```
<ion-view>
 <ion-content>
 <form>
    <label class="item item-input">
          <span><i class="icon ion-android-film"></i></span>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Company Name" ng-model="register.company_name">
    </label>
    <button class="button button-full btn-orange" ng-click="register();">Register</button>
    </form>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**JS:**

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.controller('RegisterController', function($scope, $state,$http) {
  $scope.register = function(){
        alert($scope.register.company_name);
 }
 });
```

Comment: can  u create a plunker....

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/uWJMXJL1yhAqOH7uA5uf?p=preview

Comment: it is working fine in plnkr but not in iOS App.

Comment: okay...are you getting alert on clicking any where on the screen(i.e second time alert) while using both ng-click and ng-submit?? and i cant see type=submit on button try with adding that...

Comment: yes i m getting alert twice while using both ng-click and ng-submit... it is also not working while using type= submit

Comment: try other events like on-tap instead of click

Comment: Thanks a ton... this worked for me :)

Comment: your welcome....just try other possible cases when ever fails regular ones:)-